# Adding attribute "keys" to concatenated dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am concatenating two dataframes along axis = 1 (columns) and try to use "keys" to later be able to distinguish between the columns of the two dataframes that have the same name.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'tl': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'],
            'ff': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'],
            'dd': ['z1', 'z2', 'z3', 'z4']},
            index=[2016-01-01, 2016-01-02, 2016-01-03, 2016-01-04])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'tl': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'],
            'ff': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'],
            'rf': ['z1', 'z2', 'z3', 'z4']},
            index=[2016-01-01, 2016-01-02, 2016-01-03, 2016-01-04])

data = pd.concat([df1, df2],keys=['snow','wind'], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

However, when trying to print all the columns belonging to one of the keys as suggested by @YashTD in [Pandas add keys while concatenating dataframes at column level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236830/pandas-add-keys-while-concatenating-dataframes-at-column-level)

```
print(comb_data.snow.tl)
```

I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'snow'
```

I think, the keys are just not being added to the dataframe, but I don't know why. They also don't show up wenn printing the dataframe head() at they should be suggested by 
[Pandas add keys while concatenating dataframes at column level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236830/pandas-add-keys-while-concatenating-dataframes-at-column-level)

Do you know how to add the keys to the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove parameter `ignore_index=True` for `MultiIndex` in columns and then select by `tuple`:

```
data = pd.concat([df1, df2],keys=['snow','wind'], axis=1)
print (data)
           snow         wind        
             tl  ff  dd   tl  ff  rf
2016-01-01   x1  y1  z1   x1  y1  z1
2016-01-02   x2  y2  z2   x2  y2  z2
2016-01-03   x3  y3  z3   x3  y3  z3
2016-01-04   x4  y4  z4   x4  y4  z4

print (data[('snow','tl')])
2016-01-01    x1
2016-01-02    x2
2016-01-03    x3
2016-01-04    x4
Name: (snow, tl), dtype: object
```

Comment: So the keys 'snow' and 'wind' show up with the usual print() command? Because they don't do for me, even after removing the ignore_index=True. Also unfortunately selecting by tuple throws a KeyError: ('snow', 'tl').

Comment: @Vroni - Are you sure? What is `print (data.columns)` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I additionally added column names to the dataframe, I guess they overwrite the keys and everything else. Now that I tried without column names everything shows up as you described.